# VS2010 debugging just stopped, Unknown error: 0x80072ee6

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

For some reason, my ability to attach a debugger to ANYTHING has just stopped. It has persisted after a computer reboot, and it's really making things difficult.

This is the error I get:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Unable to attach to the process. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80072ee6.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I mean, what the hell? It stopped working whilst VS2010 was running: worked for one debug, I stopped it, and then the next one didn't work.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I have tried:
a) rebooting the computer
b) regsvr32 MSXML3.dll
c) repairing MS VS2010
d) attaching the debugger manually, and by using the debug button

Comment: Just a wild guess, but can you try this: "regsvr32 MSXML3.dll". This error may be related to wininet's ERROR_INTERNET_UNRECOGNIZED_SCHEME: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193625/en-us

Comment: @Simon Mourier Nope, no dice. :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this exact problem and found that it only affected one of the projects I was working on. If I opened Visual Studio with other .sln files, they were able to attach to any process without problems. Deleting the .suo file for the affected solution didn't help, however moving the whole project to a different directory fixed the problem.

I think that Visual Studio keeps additional data for each solution file in a common location(maybe in `%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio` somewhere) and somehow that data got corrupted for that specific path to a solution file...

EDIT: I found it! Deleting the cache in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WebsiteCache` fixed the problem without me having to move the project files.

Comment: In the same spirit, CCleaner might help.

Comment: Immediately solved my issue.. I would have never found this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working again, but I'm not going to mark this as a answer.

Here's what I did:

1. Started debugging a WP7 project - success!
2. Stopped debugging the WP7 project.
3. Started debugging the ASP.Net project (runs on a remote machine) that was in the same solution as my silverlight project I was attempting to debug - success!
4. Started debugging the silverlight project I was having problems with - success!
5. Stopped debugging both
6. Started debugging just the silverlight project - success!

Apparently it works now, but as I said, but I'm not marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you whose problem wasn't solved by deleting cache, check your Project URL in:

Debug > [project name] Debug Properties > Web (tab) > Servers (section).

I had the same error as the OP, and after adding a URL into that field it cleared the issue.

Comment: This is similar to what happened to me - it seems like after a recent Windows update, the project URL has to exactly match the URL on my local machine.