# Unknown Error: 0x8ede000e Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, console

I have the full version of Visual Studio (2013) and i'm just messing with some simple C# in a console application but I keep getting this error saying that "Unable to start debugging. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x8ede000e", Any ideas on what's causing this?

Really irritating, currently having to go through the cmd and execute the program through my directory and the code runs fine with the expected output's so it's not the code.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732260/vs2010-debugging-just-stopped-unknown-error-0x80072ee6

Comment: Restart Vs and test with a new Hello World app.